# Multiple AES 256 iterations for paranoids

Tags: powershell, encryption, aes

I don't think AES256 is strong enough. If you know the expected range of characters(digits and letters) before encryption, should be easy to decrypt it with brute force attack. I tried with partially correct key and managed to see some parts of a plain text.

Eventually I came with the idea to encrypt an encrypted text multiple times. My requirement for a randomly generated key is to contain all 256 ASCII character.

Let's say that my key is 2048 bytes. Every 32 bytes of this key should encrypt a previously encrypted text. It means 2048/32 = 64 iterations.

My code below is based on https://gist.github.com/ctigeek/2a56648b923d198a6e60

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58781/does-using-the-same-encryption-algorithm-multiple-times-make-a-difference

Comment: AES-256 is strong enough if you use a good key and block chaining like CBC with a good IV.

To prevent brute-force attacks on user-provided keys (passwords), a key derivation algorithm is used (e.g. PBKDF2, scrypt).

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 3):

> I don't think AES256 is strong enough.

Such a claim you should prove. To bruteforce 128 bit key would take eons and iterate the 256 bit key way over thermal death our solar system. So far AES is not broken and you may trust people way smarter than we are. Though that assumes the key is having high entropy (is random enough).

> If you know the expected range of characters(digits and letters) before encryption, should be easy to decrypt it with brute force attack.

That has nothing to do with encryption. You are guessing values and if there is limited message space (short input message), you may guess it with non-negligible probability. No way around.

It is different if you talk about guessing the plaintext or the key material. Even the plaintext is 1 character, properly encrypted value will not reveal which if your guess is correct or not.

When you generate your key really randomly there is no way one will guess it. 256 bit is 32 bytes long. Whole issue is of the key base is short and not random (e.g. generating keys from passwords). Then we can only "patch" the weak input with salt and some key-generation function (pbkfd2, ..) which is still only workaround.

> Eventually I came with the idea to encrypt an encrypted text multiple times. My requirement for a randomly generated key is to contain all 256 ASCII character.

As already commented - there is no security improvement over encrypting multiple times and placing extra requirements to a key may even lower the key randomness.

You will have 256 bytes = 2048 bit key (= 8 x 256 keys) with 256! possibilities (which is way much less than really random key of 2^2048 possibilities). If AES itself works, 256 bits are enough. If AES will be broken, even 8 rounds (of not really radom keys) won't help you.

> I tried with partially correct key and managed to see some parts of a plain text.

Then you are doing encryption very wrong. Even having your key 1 bit off you should not be able to decrypt any part of the ciphertext.

Answer (score -1):

```
$Message = "Place here your passwords or other confidential data."

# Define how many times you want to iterate (encrypt the encrypted content) AES256 cipher
# If it's 64 means that the genrated key will be: 64 * 32 = 2048 bytes long
$AesIterations = 64

# Define your minimum requirement of unique ASCII characters.
# You may never randomly generate unique 256 chars if the iterations are less than 64
$MinUniqueChars = 256
```

### Generate encryption key

```
$aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
$aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
$aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
$aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
$aesManaged.KeySize = 256
$aesManaged.GenerateKey()

[byte[]]$bytes = @()

while (($bytes | Select-Object -Unique).Count -lt $MinUniqueChars) {

    [byte[]]$bytes = @()

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $AesIterations; $i++) {
        $aesManaged.GenerateKey()
        $bytes += $aesManaged.Key
    }   
}

$aesManaged.Dispose()
Write-Host ("`r`n Unique bytes: " + ($bytes | Select-Object -Unique).Count)
Write-Host ("`r`n Key length: " + ($bytes | Measure-Object).Count + " bytes`r`n")

# Create encryption key for later use.
$bytes | Set-Content .\mykey.key -Encoding Byte

# Get the encryption key in Base64 and export in a file.
$Base64Key = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$Base64Key | Set-Content .\Base64Key.txt -Encoding ASCII -NoNewline -Force
Write-Host " Encryption key in Base64:`r`n"
$Base64Key
```

### Encrypt the string with the key

```
$enc = Get-Content .\mykey.key -Encoding Byte

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Message)

for ($i=0; $i -lt (32 * $AesIterations); $i+=32) {
    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    $aesManaged.Key = $enc[$i..($i+31)]

    $encryptor = $aesManaged.CreateEncryptor()
    $encryptedData = $encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
    [byte[]]$bytes = $aesManaged.IV + $encryptedData

    $aesManaged.Dispose()
}

# Convert the encrypted message in Base64 and export in a file.
$EncryptedMessageBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$EncryptedMessageBase64 | Set-Content .\EncryptedInBase64.txt -Encoding ASCII -NoNewline -Force

Write-Host "`r`n Encrypted message in Base64:`r`n"
$EncryptedMessageBase64
```

### Decrypt the message with the key

```
$enc = Get-Content .\mykey.key -Encoding Byte
$bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncryptedMessageBase64)

# Since the last 32 bytes from the key were used for last iteration you have to start with them first.
# The decryption goes backwards from last 32 bytes to the beginning of your key. 
for ($i=(32 * $AesIterations) - 1; $i -gt 0; $i-=32) {

    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    $aesManaged.Key = $enc[($i-31)..$i]
    $aesManaged.IV = $bytes[0..15]

    $decryptor = $aesManaged.CreateDecryptor()
    $bytes = $decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 16, $bytes.Length - 16);
    $aesManaged.Dispose()

}

$PlainText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes).Trim([char]0)
Write-Host "`r`n Decrypted message after $AesIterations AES256 iterations:`r`n"
$PlainText
```